# On an icebreaker - any static base layers for local storage so I don't need to eat bandwidth?

Tags: basemap, offline, remote-hosting, bandwidth

I am on an icebreaker in the Arctic circle. We have StarLink, but downloading baselayers has a high failure rate. Any suggestions for a static (raster?) base layer I could pull down and just store on my local drive? We have a server pulling down ice imagery for local distribution, but the lack of a base layer is quite annoying. The online usual base layers (e.g. ESRI, Google) are not getting downloaded very well.

Comment: use GeoServer or MapProxy as a tile cache in front of your remote layers